# Add text to element in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, addition

I've got this

```
var options = new Array("text1","text2");
```

I want to add some text in each element to have Array("text1 someothertext","text2 sometext");

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what have you tried that didn't work? This seems trivial.

Comment: And where does "someothertext" and "sometext" come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can access Array with the brackets [] notation (0 based index):

```
options[0] += " someothertext";
options[1] += " sometext";
```

Comment: This seems rather manual doesn't it? What if the array is 1000 items long?

Comment: Yep.. But I didn't get the point of the question to give a more accurated response :/ too vanal question